# In OctoberCMS how do you find the hint path?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, content-management-system, octobercms

```
Mail::sendTo($to, 'OctoberCMS.PhotoElegance::mail.contactform', $params);
```

When this line of code is called I get back an error which says the following:
"No hint path defined for [OctoberCMS.PhotoeElgance] on line 112 of  vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php"

In simple, I am trying to send mail when the contact form is submitted. The code is inside a function called onStart(). I discovered that the appname is OctoberCMS. After the dot I have PhotoElegance as that is the website name.

After the hint path (OctoberCMS.PhotoElegance) I am calling the static function (mail.contactform) to my defined contact form which has been built in the CMS.

Where do I find out the appname and website name. How do I define these if I want to change them. I understand this is to do with name spacing but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi the way you try to send an email is called ["Mail view"](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail#mail-views) this is the way you do send mail form a plugin, and the path to the mail view is author.plugin::path.to.view.

From the very short definition of your problem i can tell that you are not using plugin but the dynamic pages feature of october cms so you must use ["mail template"](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail#mail-templates) .

Go to setting > find mail->mail template in the left side bar > click new template  chose a code once done you can use this tempalte to send email from dynamic page.

```
Mail::sendTo($to, 'template.code', $params);
```